# Should pc's level for killing one another 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, problem-players, character-levels

I just started the book campaign "The Sunless Citadel" and everyone is new, not new to rpg just new to this particular fashion, they all love the fact I give "limited free will" but that's not the issue, the issue is that they have spent the last 3 hours of one session fighting rope. Really it was a lot of critical fails. But later on a new player entered, he chose an evil rogue and I was ok with it for the sake of the lawful good paladin, I was into it. Well in short things went downhill fast and the paladin got him. Then another party member known for being shady as hell  tries to step in fails and he cuts him down to. There were obvious warnings such as, *I hold my blade to you and ask you dare oppose the laws of Pelor?!* and he runs at him so he in defense cut him down, well the barbarian runs over and cuts his head off that 3 dead that's half of the party. So should I give a level to them? On top of that I felt really bad, so I gave him a single roll that can keep you from death and Pelor, his god, brings him back to life for a "higher calling" I'm just not sure, all the behavior was justified, so I want to but at the same time I'm conflicted.

Comment: You ask whether you should give your players a level for killing each other, but you've tagged the question "problem players", which suggests to me that you are not exactly *happy* for your PCs infighting. So which is the actual core of your question: whether your players should be allowed to fight each other, or whether they should be rewarded for it?

Comment: While editing your post, take a look at this: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it because it sounds like it could help you identify the issues you see with the game.

Comment: They do, pending on the laws of said area and what is going on, example: the barbarian walked into the city, unable to read he picked up a guy threatening him asking where he could get a drink, the guy fearful drunk and angry, told him in a slur of points ting and drunkenness and said yes y oh better put me down and then the barbarian killed him then pow the guards show up, it's not so much the literal saying of it so much as there's a reaction to most of their actions that then limits alot.